# Custom WIF scenario

Tags: wif

I have a scenario that might have been asked before. I want to use WIF with a windows client but my STS would be behind a firewall and I need to augment the STS to deal with custom authentication. The call flow would be Client - calls authenticate on Security Service with custom RST claims token - Security Service - calls existing asmx service to validate user  and retrives custom athentication values - Security Service - calls custom STS to create a Saml2 token and sends it back down to the client.

Once back on the client I have a secured token that I can use to call other WCF services that are WIF enabled.

Any examples on how this could work? Or did I miss n understanding somewhere in all my reading?

Thanks,

Comment: What are you using for your STS?  I don't see anything too out-of-the-ordinary with what you're proposing.

Answer (score 1):

The network requirements in this scenario are:

1. The STS needs to be reachable by the client
2. The WCF service needs to be reachable from the client
3. The user validation ASMX service needs to be reachable by the STS

There are many examples of #1 and #2. It's all fairly standard. Look in the WIF SDK or the "Active" samples in [the claims guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx). Calling a custom ASMX to validate a user is well....custom. An implementation detail of your STS (which would have to be custom too, not an off-the-shelf STS like ADFS v2)

Comment: Thanks Eugenio, So I can't create a custom SAML2 token and pass that to my service and have the service manage the call to the STS and authenticate to the exiting asmx service? Right? What about just passing a Custom SAML 2.0 token and populating that token with my custome claims and returning it to the client to be used with other services? I apologise for the Noob questions but I'm just starting to learn the in's and out's of Cliams and WIF.

Comment: The "Claims Guide" I put a link to in the answer explains the flow between service, client and STS. In general, the STS is never called by the service directly. There's a trust relationship between the two meaning that a token signed by the STS will be deemed "trusted". A token issued by a client and sent to the service would defeat the purpose. The method used by the STS to issue a token is something between the STS and the client (e.g. passwords, certs, secrets, iris scan, whatever). The goal being that your app is isolated from thios details.